# Solving an elliptic integral

Tags: calculus, integration

so at the moment I am stuck at an integral of this form, maybe someone could help me.

$$\int \frac{dr}{r^{2}\sqrt{c+\frac{b}{r^{2}}+ar^{2}}}$$

Comment: This is not an elliptic integral, since the solution is analytic and it is:

$$\frac{r \sqrt{a r^4+b+c r^2} \left(2 \log (r)-\log \left(2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{a r^4+b+c r^2}+2 b+c r^2\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{r^2 \left(a r^4+b+c r^2\right)}}$$

Comment: Do you only need the solution or also how to comu up with it? Are there any conditions on $a,b,c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an elliptic integral. Assuming the integration range is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$ and the polynomial $b+cr^2+ar^4$ has no positive root,
$$\int \frac{dr}{r\sqrt{b+cr^2+a r^4}}\stackrel{r\mapsto\sqrt{u}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u\sqrt{b+cu+au^2}}. $$
By a suitable affine substitution the problem boils down to computing
$$ \int \frac{du}{(Au+B)\sqrt{u^2+1}}\stackrel{u\mapsto\sinh t}{=}\int\frac{dt}{A\sinh t+B} $$
and the further substitution $t=\log z$ turns the last integral into an elementary integral, which can be tackled through partial fraction decomposition.